# Mark-up for bold and italic in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In emacs org-mode, we can use mark-ups to set [Emphasis and monospace](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html).
e.g.

***bold***

/*italic*/

How can we make a word both bold and italic?
It seems neither */.../* nor /*...*/ works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fact, both of these *do* work.

```
/*test*/
```

exports to HTML as

```
<i><b>test</b></i>
```

`*/test/*` works similarly. LaTeX / PDF export also works as you expect.

Org itself doesn't fontify both the bold and italic, but the semantics are fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Emacs in Windows (as GUI). In org-mode, I can hide the markup symbols and see the effect of **bold** and *italic* by *(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)*. But when I use both, only the outer markup takes effect.

Comment: @dzhu, yes, that's what I said. Emacs doesn't fontify italics with bold but the semantics are correct, as you can see when exporting.

Comment: @Chris with some gymnastics org can fontify multiple markups, see my answer below

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @Chris answer covering semantics being there, if you're interested in visible *fontification effect inside your org notes*, you have three approaches:

### Highlight parts of your text

[image]

Nesting works nicely as long as you don't need to start / end two tags at once.

### Use multiple tags with escape symbols

The closest you can get is

[image: fontification emacs]

The code is:
`*\ /\ _\ ~fontification can be nested~\_\/\*`

So you need `\​​ ​` (backslash and space) to escape following opening tags and `\` (backslash) to escape following closing tags.

The need for space is annoying, and in it looks like this when exported to html:
[image: fontification html]

So yes, you can have multiple mark-ups at once, but you have to choose between seeing the effect in emacs or having it nicely formated on export.

### Modify how markup looks in emacs

Alternatively you could change how mark-up looks in emacs without modyfing exporting format, i.e. to make bold look red you'd need this:

```
(add-to-list 'org-emphasis-alist
         '("*" (:foreground "red")
           ))
```

as covered in [this great question and answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-in-org-mode).